# Exception - Call to undefined function navigation_get_string() in moodle

Tags: moodle, moodle-api, moodle-mobile

I have a strange problem after updating custem menu navigation to moodle 3.2.2 and Fordson theme.  The error is:

```
 Call to undefined function navigation_get_string()
```

Do you know how I would be able to fix this please?

Answer (score 0):

There's a small, easy-to-fix bug in the **fordson_lib.php** file in the theme.

The bug is around 350 and looks like this:

```
        if ($parent) {
             $childnode = $pmasternode->add(navigation_get_string($menunode->get_text()), $url, navigation_node::TYPE_CUSTOM);
        $childnode->title($menunode->get_title());
```

**navigation_get_string** needs to be changed to **fordson_local_navigation_get_string**.

If you're having trouble finding it, you could search for **(navigation_get_string**.

I have submitted this bug and fix to the developer so that it gets back into the repository.

One other thought: this custom menu area is just for the nav drawer. If you are trying to adjust the custom menu area that is in the nav bar, you need to go to **Site admin / Appearance / Themes / Theme settings**.